# Select all data in sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a macro that opens a New Workbook and copies all data to a different Workbook.
The data always starts on C12 but we dont always know how many rows of data there are

The following code is giving an error:

```
Workbooks("Somesheet.xls").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
 With Range("C12").Select
 End (xlDown)
 End With
```

How do I select all rows from C12?

Answer (score 2):

```
dim rng as range
with Workbooks("Somesheet.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").range("C12")
    set rng = range(.cells(0,0), .end(xldown))
end with
```

You could also use

```
set rng = Workbooks("Somesheet.xls").range("C12").CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Why not usedrange http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa218185(v=office.10).aspx? The sheet is just opened, so it should be fine.

Comment: The first example creates a range starting from D22 which is C12+B11 (B11 == range("C12").Cells(0, 0)). The last cell is C12+CXX where XX is the row number of the last contiguous cell in Column C after C12. For example, if the last cell is C30, the resulting range is D22:E41. The desired result is C12:C30 or if more columns exist past C, C12:xx30 where xx is the last column.

Comment: looking up from the last cell in C using `xlup` would avoid the blank cells issue that `xldown` may encounter (depending on whether the data is contiguous). Although if the last data was in a hidden rows then the look down/ups wont get the correct position.

Answer (score 1):

In order to select all data from cell C12 down, use the `UsedRange` property to find the absolute last row used. Other methods will stop before the true end of the sheet if there is a blank cell in Column C. This snippet sets a Range variable that spans from C12 to the last used cell in the sheet:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim lRowLast As Long, lColLast As Long
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lRowLast = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    lColLast = .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("C12"), .Cells(lRowLast, lColLast))
End With
```

Note: use `.Row + .Rows.Count - 1` to handle cases where the used range starts after the first row.

**Edit:** Updated example to fix the bug that @brettdj pointed out.

Comment: +1 For the updated solution (be cautious if there are hidden rows though)

Answer (score 1):

I use Find to detect the true last used cell as UsedRange can be unreliable with over- estimating the extent of the true used range unless it is forced to recalc in the code before being used. UsedRange can also be problematic unless it start from A1 (I had this issue with Rachel's code when testing data only in C12:C40, the answer provided was G34:G60)

From your question sample code it appears you only wanted column C data from C12 down (which is what this code does). It can readily be extended accross the true used range of columns, or as entire rows if needed

```
Sub GetData()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set wb = Workbooks("SomeSheet.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns("C").Find("*", ws.[c1], xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng1.Row > 12 Then
        Set rng2 = ws.Range(ws.[c12], rng1)
        MsgBox "Your range is " & rng2.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        MsgBox "Last row in " & ws.Name & " was only " & rng1.Row
    End If
End Sub
```